# Use of "it" after "in such a way that"

Tags: sentence-structure, conjunctions, relative-pronouns

Which of the following is correct? The only difference between them is the presence of the word "it".

1- Describe your accomplishments in such a way **that highlights** how they might be relevant to the employer.

2- Describe your accomplishments in such a way **that *it* highlights** how they might be relevant to the employer.

Comment: (1) should omit 'such'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you for your response. Does your answer change if I replace "your accomplishments" with the pronoun "them" in the above example?

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for your response. Does your answer change if I replace "your accomplishments" with the pronoun "them" in the above example?

Comment: Note that syntactically it makes no difference if you replace ***in such a way*** by just ***such***, which should make it more obvious that you only want to include ***it*** if you also have ***such*** (whether or not it's "wrapped" in ***in ... a way***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers If one uses "such that", then I think the pronoun that follows should be "they" instead of "it". So "such that" and "in such a way that" are kind of different. Do you agree?

Comment: Well, ***it*** effectively references the *description*, whereas ***they*** references the *accomplishments*. But to my ear, the ***it*** version is always gonna sound a bit awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option number 1 - "Describe your accomplishments in such a way that highlights how they might be relevant to the employer." seems right to me because "that" is a subject of a dependent clause and means "way". So using "it" here will be just the repeating of a subject.